# how does Android store the information of where app icons are placed in screen?

Tags: android, launcher

My question may sound silly: how does Android (launcher) store the information of where app icons are?

Does it depend on specific phone model (launcher type), or is there any public APIs?

[image]

For example, suppose this is the first screen, and the **Youtube** is at the first row, second column. How can I get this coordinate? or How can I know the app at `(row=x, column=y)` ?

Comment: My guess is that this depends on the launcher app.